# How do you add a JAVA TimeStamp for my SQL to work?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have to make a Refuge program which saves the information on a database; I'm having problem with the date_entry Variable since I'm not sure how to implement it. The database says that the entry for this should be in TimeStamp, but im not sure how to make it work on my code; tried making a function and then assign the function to my variable but yeah, didn't work. I added the database just in case. This is what i got until now:

```
JButton btnInsert = new JButton("Insert");
        btnInsert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String name = txtPetName.getText();
                String photo = txtPetPhoto.getText();
                String type = txtPetType.getText();
                String color = txtColor.getText();
                int gender = Integer.parseInt(txtGender.getText());
                int isSterilized = Integer.parseInt(txtSterlized.getText());
                String pedigree = txtPedigree.getText();
                String dateEntry =  showDate();         //HERE'S MY DOUBT>
                String vaccine1 = txtVaccine1.getText();
                String vaccine2 = txtVaccine2.getText();
                String vaccine3 = txtVaccine3.getText();

                Connection conn = null;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

                try {

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/refugio","root","2797");
                    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PETS VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    pstmt.setString(1, name);
                    pstmt.setString(2, photo);
                    pstmt.setString(3, type);
                    pstmt.setString(4, color);
                    pstmt.setInt(5, gender);
                    pstmt.setInt(6, isSterilized);
                    pstmt.setString(7, pedigree);
                    pstmt.setString(8, showDate()); //THEN HERE
                    pstmt.setString(9, vaccine1);
                    pstmt.setString(10, vaccine2);
                    pstmt.setString(11, vaccine3);
                    int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();

                    if(i>0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data was saved");
                    }else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data was not saved");
                    }


                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        btnInsert.setBounds(29, 715, 379, 54);
        contentPane.add(btnInsert);
/**
DATABASE:
CREATE DATABASE refugio;

USE refugio;

CREATE TABLE Pets
(
   petName VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   petPhoto VARCHAR(50) NULL,
   petType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   color VARCHAR(15),
   gender TINYINT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - female, 1 - male',
   isSterilized TINYINT(1) COMMENT '0 - NO, 1 - YES',
   pedigree VARCHAR(15),
   date_entry timestamp NOT NULL,
   vaccine1 VARCHAR(15) NULL,
   vaccine2 VARCHAR(15) NULL,
   vaccine3 VARCHAR(15) NULL
);
*/
```

Comment: Maybe with `date_entry TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Way too much irrelevant code. When posting here, reduce code to the bare minimum needed to show your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(timestamp);
```

credits: [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-current-timestamps-in-java/)

Comment: The froublesome `Timestamp` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by `OffsetDateTime` in JDBC 4.2 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) type in MySQL is akin to the standard SQL type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

The appropriate Java class is [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

Capture the current moment as seen in a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Extract an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Send to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

This has been covered *many* times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.